# Dynamic resource allocation for spark applications not working

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark and trying to figure out how dynamic resource allocation works. I have spark structured streaming application which is trying to read million records at a time from Kafka and process them. My application always starts with 3 executors and never increase the number of executors.

It takes 5-10 minutes to finish the processing. I thought it will increase the number of executors(up to 10) and try to finish the processing sooner, which is not happening.What am I missing here? How is this supposed to work?

I have set below properties in Ambari for Spark

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = true
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors = 3
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors = 10
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors = 3
spark.shuffle.service.enabled = true
```

Below is how my submit command looks like

```
/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/spark2/bin/spark-submit --class com.sb.spark.sparkTest.sparkTest --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --queue default sparkTest-assembly-0.1.jar
```

**Spark code**

```scala
//read stream
val dsrReadStream = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers) //kafka bokers
   .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsets) // start point to read
   .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", maxoffsetpertrigger) // no. of records per batch
   .option("failOnDataLoss", "true")

 /****
 Logic to validate format of loglines. Writing invalid log lines to kafka and store valid log lines in 'dsresult'

 ****/

//write stream
val dswWriteStream =dsresult.writeStream
    .outputMode(outputMode) // file write mode, default append
    .format(writeformat) // file format ,default orc
    .option("path",outPath) //hdfs file write path
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointdir) location
    .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 999999999) 
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerTimeInMins))
```

Comment: How many Kafka partitions do you have?

Comment: 3 kafka partitions

Comment: So there is no reason for your application to ever request more resources. Three Kafka partitions -> 3 Spark partitions -> 3 executors, even at single core each are enough to achieve maximum parallelism.

Comment: Currently it takes approx 5-7 mins to process million records with 3 executors. I've tested the same with 6 executors and it takes comparatively less time. If I set max executors as 10, shouldn't it use more executors (more than 3, if available) dynamically to increase the processing time?My ideal expected processing time is less than 2 minutes. Should I increase initial executors to achieve this?Please advise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dynamic Resource Allocation does not work with Spark Streaming

[Refer this link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/configuring-spark/content/configuring_dynamic_resource_allocation.html)

Comment: spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to Clarify further,

> spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true

worked only for Dstreams API. See [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12133)

Also, if you set

> spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true

and run a structured streaming job, the batch dynamic allocation algorithm kicks in, which may not be very optimal. See [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24815)